# Scanning to finds active working webservers (nmap?)

Tags: shell, unix, networking, nmap

I need an nmap command or other utility that finds open sites so I can do a survey on them. The problem is that when I use nmap it finds IPs of sites that are not working:

```
nmap -iR 200 -p 80 > scan.txt
```

I'd like it to show in the result sites like Google; Amazon; or whatever, they just need to be actual sites with some content on them.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Are you planning to scan the whole internet?

Comment: Please capitalize conventionally.

Comment: not the whole internet, just 2000 or so IPs

Comment: Your cause would be helped by adding the command-line you ran and a portion of the result it returned.

Comment: i'm running:
nmap -iR 200 -p 80 > scan.txt
i get the ip and open/filtered/closed

the open ip turn out to be passowrd protected or not working sites.
What i'd like is just to fund working sites like google.

Comment: Word of advice, do not paste the output on a text file because that will require you to parse it. Nmap output has changed a lot during the years, as I suggested in my answer use -oX instead and parse the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I got your question but if you have a list of those sites stored in a file you can use the following command:

```
nmap -iL yourfile -v -oX nmap.xml
```

This command will store the result on an XML file that should help you gathering the information you need.

However if you do not have a list and you just want to find "working" sites well.... in that case I don't know how you can do that with Nmap. Nmap scans a target. Host (site?) discovery works when you scan a LAN or VPN network but since sites are supposed to be on the Internet your question does not make so much sense. However I repeat, I am not quite sure I understand your question.

EDIT: Ok maybe now I got what you mean, if the problem is Nmap giving you false results you may try to improve the scan with some more aggressive parameter such as -A and -v. Please notice that scan random computers over the Internet (expecially if you do an aggressive scan) may not be exactly legal. Well honestly I don't really know about that but I suggest yout to gather more information before scanning.

Comment: Ok, I thought of using nmap but probably i was wrong, I'm kind of a noob to be honest. I need some program/utility to get me random working sites so i can make a survey on them (that is finding the most used word for example). What i need is basically a list of random working sites... The problem is that i can't use an already made list. I have to do the list and use it.
I hope i explained myself.

Thx a lot for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Nmap 6 has been released, if you look at the release notes it looks like web scanning has been improved. [Check it out](http://nmap.org/6/).

Comment: In the end it was not doable with nmap. Atleast not in an efficient way (if you can wait hours to find an address that's ok.. but seem crazy). Thanks a lot everyone for helping!